# Regression and classification Insight

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

I've a problem that in the same time looks like Regression and classification

I have a dataset with:

- Categories of services.
- Who did the services.
- The delay that the person took to finish such project.
- And the client who asked for the services.

For new coming work, I want to know, to whom I'm I going to allocate the project, so that it's done without delay. I would like to receive some insight from you.

Comment: You could improve the question with example code and more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both.

But I don't think either makes sense on such data.